# Bernoulli Lemniscate - surface area and volume

Tags: calculus, volume, area

> How do I calculate the surface area and volume of the solid obtained by rotating the Bernoulli lemniscate
>   $$(x^2+y^2)^2=2a^2(x^2-y^2)$$
>   around the $x$-axis?

It is not like I'm lazy and asking for a ready solution, or completely helpless. I really tried to calculate this and I failed. That is why I'm asking for help :)

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Could help if you added some details. Not everyone knows what a Bernoulli lemniscate is.

Comment: What counts as a solution, e.g,., is the definite integral formula for surface area and volume not suitable for you?  After all, it's not as if the *arc length* of the lemniscate is some familiar number (a new letter can be introduced for it, but that's not quite solving it).

Answer (score 1):

The solution in the polar coordinates system where the lemniscate is given by the formula $r^{2}=2a^{2}\cos2\phi$.

Surface area can be obtained by using the formula $A=2\pi\int_a^br(\phi)\sin\phi\sqrt{r^{2}(\phi)+[dr(\phi)/d\phi]^{2}}d\phi$: 
 $$A=2\pi a^{2}\sqrt{a}\int_a^b\sin\phi\sqrt{\cos2\phi +sin^{2}2\phi } d\phi$$ 
The integral above seems to have no analytical solutions.

The formula for the volume is pretty simple and can be obtained directly from the formula $V=\pi\int_a^b  r^2(\phi)d\phi$ :
$$V=2a^{2}\pi\int_a^b  cos2\phi d\phi$$

Answer (score 1):

I think the valid solution is on the photo below (the little picture is just to show the idea of the lemniscate). There might be some minor algebra errors but I believe this is the right way to solve this problem. 
  There’s a small mistake in the limits of integration, it should be, say,  from c to d, to avoid confusion about ‘a’ as the  limit and ‘a’ as the parameter of the lemniscate.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See the image **(https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6cBL.png).**
Equation -: **(x^2 + y^2)^2 = r^2*(x^2 - y^2)**.
If the maximum distance from the center of the Lemniscate of Bernoulli (origin) to the end point on x-axis is **'r'**, then **Volume** obtained will be **0.45536*(r^3)** and **Surface Area** will be **1.36608*(r^2)**.
For proof, mail me at **rasikrastogi@gmail.com** .